# TFS 2010 Build Defaults - Third option?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I was setting up a new build definition today and noticed there is an option 'Copy build output to the following Source Control folder'. I don't *believe* I have seen this before. It *appears* to me from searching google that it *might* be new as of TFS 11 (AKA TFS 2012) which I do not have installed on my system (or any system in my company network to my knowledge). My company uses TFS 2010 right now.

I went to another user who is able to view build definitions and it also was present when the build definitions were viewed.

This is what i see:

[image]

My questions:

1) Was this a part of TFS 2010 and I am just not remembering seeing it?

2) If this IS part of TFS 2010, how to enable this option (it is disabled).

3) If this is NOT a part of TFS 2010, how did it get there?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is part of TFS 2010, but I have no idea how it got here!
2. I believe this is for those who use TFS 'as a service' (when you
   have no file share to copy it to). According to
   [how-can-i-copy-build-output-to-the-source-control-folder](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52571d4c-5719-4481-a48b-fece8d0f8cf1/how-can-i-copy-build-output-to-the-source-control-folder?forum=tfsbuild)
3. I have this in TFS/VS 2010 (SP1):

[image]

Comment: Let me get back to you on which version. I see it NOT available in 2010, however I do see it on one of my 2010 SP1 machines. I am applying VS updates to see if it then appears

Comment: That is what I am wondering. Everywhere I look I see it says TFS 11 which I believe is TFS 2012. I'm puzzled.

Comment: The machine where I see it, I have 2010, 2012, and 2013 installed. Where I do NOT see it (where I have just 2010), installing SP1 does not make the option available. Why? WHY?

Comment: Was it available before sp1?